# Where can I find Sahasranama Stotrams of Sri RamaKrishna, Shirdi Sai and Satya Sai Baba?

Tags: avatars, ramakrishna, sai

We have three major avatars in Kali yuga till now. Sri RamaKrishna paramahans, Sri Shirdi Sai and Sri Satya Sai baba.

Where can I get their sahasranama stotrams? In addition to Sanskrit an English or Hindi translation would be better.

What are the benefits of daily reciting them?

Comment: Sahasranamas for Saints?

Comment: @TheDestroyer edited tag now

Comment: @Partha I found them online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sahasranama stotras :

Sri RamaKrishna paramhans sahasranama can be downloaded from https://archive.org/details/SriRamakrishnaSahasranamaStotramTABhandarkar1979_201806/page/n17

The benefits of reciting this is descried here: https://archive.org/details/SriRamakrishnaSahasranamaStotramTABhandarkar1979_201806/page/n11

> By reading this Sanskrit book the devotees will be able to meditate
>   upon and understand the significance of Holy incarnation of Lord Sri
>   RamaKrishna. Those who read or recite this partially will be blessed
>   by Sri Thakur and Holy mother.

Sri Shirdi Sai Sahasranama can be read from here:

http://www.shirdisaimandiryazali.com/sahasranamam or
http://www.shirdisaibabadhuni.com/sri-sai-sahasranama-archana-1000-blessings-of-shirdi-saibaba/

The benefits are:

> 1. If one dally repeats Sai’s names and meditates on Sai, then he will surely attain (Dharma) Virtue, (Artha) wealth, (Kama) enjoyment and
>      (Moksha) Salvation. There is no doubt about this.
> 2. The issueless, will thus obtain issue; the poor, wealth; the student Learning and the maiden will obtain a good husband.
> 3. Sai who loves the devotees who have surreendered themselves to Him gives everything to them, (so) seek refuge with Sai, who grants boons
>      beneficial in this world and beyond.

Sri Satya Sai Sahasranama can be read from here:

http://www.saibaba.ws/prayers/1008names.htm

Comment: The Sri Ramakrishna Sahasranama reads very nice BTW.Thanks.:)